# Orders of $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question:

Is $|[G:H]|=|[G:gHg^{-1}]|$? For any $g$ in $G$

I think that this is true. 
I would prove this by using the well known argument that for any g in G $|H|=|gH|$ and the same is true for $H$ and $Hg^{-1}$ which would give us to our conclusion, however my gut tells me that this is weak reasoning. So does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Explicitly, there is a bijection
$$\{\text{cosets of $H$}\}\to \{\text{cosets of $gHg^{-1}$}\}$$
given by
$$kH\mapsto (gkg^{-1})gHg^{-1} = g(kH)g^{-1}$$
for $k\in G$, with inverse
$$k'(gHg^{-1})\mapsto (g^{-1}k'g)H.$$

(This map is well-defined: if $kH=k'H$, then clearly $g(kH)g^{-1} = g(k'H)g^{-1}$. The more "obvious" map given by $kH\mapsto kgHg^{-1}$ would only be well-defined if $H$ was normal in $G$.)

Conjugation can be thought of as a change of reference in the group, similarly to the way that conjugation of matrices represents a change of basis in a vector space. The two groups $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are isomorphic (via the map $h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$), and sit inside $G$ in the same way.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  Let $G = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1 = 0 \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots$, and $H_2 = 0 \times 0 \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots$.  Then $H_1 \cong H_2$, but $[G:H_1] = 2$ and $[G:H_2] = 4$.  The isomorphism $H_1 \cong H_2$ is not conjugation, but this example at least shows that isomorphic subgroups need not have the same index in the containing group.

Comment: @SpamIAm You're right in the infinite case. I implicitly assumed $G$ was finite. I've changed the answer.